# scrapy xpath selector without same DIV ID

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

i want to select all divs that a first part of their ID is "edit" using scrapy/XPATH.
For example:

```
<div id="edit3423432">...</div>
<div id="edit0036594">...</div>
```

For divs which have same id i use this code:

```
hxs.select('.//div[contains(@id,"testid")]')
```

But now how can i select all divs that have the first four characters equal to "edit"?

Comment: Am not sure for xpath but as far as CSS goes it can be written as `div[id^="edit"]`

Comment: I want to note that Scrapy has a `.css` function where you actually can do `.css(div[id^=edit])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath has a special function called `starts-with`, that would be pretty ideal here. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
hxs.select('.//div[starts-with(@id, 'edit')]')
```

Hope that helps, let me know if you have any questions.